# LUIS deployed through SharePoint - How to get user data?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

We have deployed LUIS V4 in our Azure Platform, and made it available to our employee through SharePoint. It is currently open and does not need log in to be used.

We would like to capture information about who the person interacting with the bot is; is there any way that information related to the user can be retrieved? (employees to use the bot must be authenticated to Azure as it is within a SharePoint, but the bot doesn't require authentication as mentioned)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are just using LUIS, then no, it does not do any user specific tasks. It only translates an utterance (phrase) into specific actions (intents and entities), also does not store any state.

So all authorisations and user customisations need to be done outside of LUIS, with plain code. If you are using Azure/Microsoft Bot, you can hook up a channel to LUIS and use the id to identify user (skype id, phone number, microsoft teams id...)

A bit of [info](https://roshanalmas.wordpress.com/2017/09/13/spbotframework1/) for connecting Azure Bot with SharePoint.